# Is it possible to enter developer mode on an ASUS Chromebox using an Apple Keyboard?

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook

I have an ASUS Chromebox (CN62), and I'd like to enter developer mode so that I'm able to install other Linux distros, following instructions here: https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices/asus-chromebox#TOC-Developer-Mode

I've connected the keyboard to the Chromebox via USB, but nothing happens when I press `Ctrl + D` on the Recovery Screen.

If I boot into ChromeOS as usual, the keyboard works normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the keyboard was the issue. I was able to enter developer mode using a wired keyboard